# ethers.js contract function calls keep failing

Tags: solidity, remix, ethers.js

I am trying out my first Solidity project; a todo app. I have worked on the smart contract using remix and tested all its functions, which work as intended. I worked on my frontend and connected it using ethers.js and functions like `addTodo`, `clearAllTasks` work perfectly well except the function to get all the tasks.

This is the error I keep getting:

```
index.js:160 Error fetching todos: Error: call revert exception (method="getTodos()", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.2.0)
```

and this is the code I run to get all the tasks:

```js
async function getTasks() {
  try {
    const todos = await TodoContract.getTodos();
    console.log("Todos:", todos);
    return todos;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching todos:", error);
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me out?

here is the smart contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
```

pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

contract Todo{

```
struct TodoItem {
   string  task;
  bool  completed;
}

TodoItem[] public todoList;

function addTodo  (string memory task) public {
   todoList.push(TodoItem(task, false));
}


function getTodos () public view returns(TodoItem[] memory){
```

return todoList;
}

```
function updateTodo(uint256 index) public  {
    require(index < todoList.length, "index out of range");
    todoList[index].completed = true;
}

function deleteTodo (uint256 index) public {
```

require(index < todoList.length, "index out of range");
todoList[index] = todoList[todoList.length - 1];
todoList.pop();
}

```
function clearAll () public {
   delete todoList;
}

function editTodo (uint256 index, string memory updateValue) public {
```

require(!todoList[index].completed, "todo already completed, set another todo");
todoList[index].task = updateValue;
}
}

the abi and smart contract address are correct as other parts of the smart contract are interacting properly.

here is a part of my abi

```
 {
inputs: [],
name: "getTodos",
outputs: [
  {
    components: [
      {
        internalType: "string",
        name: "task",
        type: "string",
      },
      {
        internalType: "bool",
        name: "completed",
        type: "bool",
      },
    ],
    internalType: "struct Todo.TodoItem[]",
    name: "",
    type: "tuple[]",
  },
],
stateMutability: "view",
type: "function",
```

},

Answer (score 0):

is there a method named `getTodos()` in your contract????
please share codes here.

also, maybe you need to add `.call()` at the end of the const todos = await TodoContract.getTodos();

Comment: hii
i just updated the question
and i tried to add call(), said call() is not a function